# Inverse of perturbed triangular matrix

Tags: matrix-calculus

For an ill-conditioned triangular matrix $T$, can we give a simple expression for the following

$$(T + \Delta T)^{-1}$$

where $|\Delta T| \leq \epsilon|T|$, $\epsilon \ll 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Using Taylor formula, we obtain $(T+\Delta T)^{-1}= T^{-1}-T^{-1}.\Delta T. T^{-1}+O(||\Delta T||^2||T^{-1}||^3)=$

$T^{-1}-T^{-1}.\Delta T. T^{-1}+O(\epsilon ^2.cond^2(T).||T^{-1}||)$.

Then you must choose $\epsilon \ll \dfrac{1}{cond(T)}$.

Comment: What if $\epsilon \approx cond(T)$?

Comment: @ DDaren.  If $T$ is ill-conditioned, then $cond(T)$ can be $10^8$ and more.

Comment: Sorry I mean $\epsilon \approx 1/cond(T)$. Can you still use Taylor series when $\epsilon \geq 1/cond(T)$? In my case $\epsilon$ is fixed but $T$ is not.

Comment: I see that I spent my time.